# Complete subsequence in Traminer

Tags: r, subsequence, traminer

Subsequences functions give interesting results with the seqefsub function. I work on sequences composed of geographical locations. Is there a way to know whether the subsequence listed is a complete subsequence.

I provide an example.

```
library(TraMineR)
id = c(rep(1,5), rep(2,3), rep(3,3), rep(4,3), rep(5,2),  rep(6,2), rep(7,3), rep(8,3))
begin = c(1963, 1969, 1969, 1974, 2004, 1971, 1976, 1984, 1996, 1998, 2011, 1997, 2008, 2011, 1967, 1971, 1972, 1985, 1971, 1980, 1986, 1974, 2000, 2002)
end = c(1969, 1969, 1974, 2004, 2012, 1976, 1984, 2012, 1998, 2011, 2012, 2008, 2011, 2012, 1971, 2012, 1985 ,2012 ,1980 ,1986 ,2012 ,2000 ,2002 ,2012)
status = c(1, 5, 6, 5, 1, 1, 5, 1, 1, 3, 8, 1, 3, 1, 1, 5, 1, 8, 1, 5, 1, 1, 8, 1)
df = data.frame(id,begin,end,status)
df.seq1 = seqformat(df, from = "SPELL", to="STS", process = FALSE)
df.seq2 <- seqdef(df.seq1, informat='STS')
df.seq3 <- seqecreate(df.seq2, tevent = "transition")

fsubseq <-seqefsub(df.seq3, min.support = 1)
```

There are 8 sequences where status corresponds to different geographical locations. Time unit is a year.
The function fsubseq lists all possible subsequences.

```
             Subsequence Support Count
1                    (*)   0.875     7
2              (*)-(*>1)   0.875     7
3                  (*>1)   0.875     7
4        (*)-(*>1)-(1>5)   0.375     3
5              (*)-(1>5)   0.375     3
6            (*>1)-(1>5)   0.375     3
7                  (1>5)   0.375     3
8                  (5>1)   0.375     3
9        (*)-(*>1)-(1>3)   0.250     2
10 (*)-(*>1)-(1>5)-(5>1)   0.250     2
11       (*)-(*>1)-(1>8)   0.250     2
12       (*)-(*>1)-(5>1)   0.250     2
13             (*)-(1>3)   0.250     2
14       (*)-(1>5)-(5>1)   0.250     2
15             (*)-(1>8)   0.250     2
16             (*)-(5>1)   0.250     2
17           (*>1)-(1>3)   0.250     2
18     (*>1)-(1>5)-(5>1)   0.250     2
19           (*>1)-(1>8)   0.250     2
20           (*>1)-(5>1)   0.250     2
21                 (1>3)   0.250     2
22           (1>5)-(5>1)   0.250     2
23                 (1>8)   0.250     2
```

what i call the "complete subsequence" correspond to the subsequences that encompass all successive states for one individual. In this examples, there are seven: 1/6/5/1, 1/5/1,1/3/8, 1/3/1, 1/5, 1/8, 1/8/1. The "complete subsequence" 1/5/1 corresponds to line 10.
It is difficult to spot in the list the "complete subsequence". So my question is to know whether there is a way to filter from the list the complete subsequence.

Comment: Read [ask] and [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, what you call "complete subsequences" are the sequences of distinct successive states.

The distinct successive states are obtained from the state sequences with `seqdss`, and the frequencies of the sequences with `seqtab`. So, we get frequencies of what you call "complete subsequences" with:

```
seqtab(seqdss(df.seq2))
#                 Freq Percent
# 1/1-5/1-1/1        2      25
# 1/1-3/1-1/1        1      12
# 1/1-3/1-8/1        1      12
# 1/1-5/1            1      12
# 1/1-6/1-5/1-1/1    1      12
# 1/1-8/1            1      12
# 1/1-8/1-1/1        1      12
```